# animation on mouseover event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

```
document.getElementById("both-gif").onmouseover=function() {MouseOver()};

document.getElementById("both-gif").onmouseout=function() {MouseOut()};



function MouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("both-gif").addClass("animated bounce")
}

function MouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("both-gif").removeClass("animated bounce")
}
```

Im trying to make my gif-image bounce, it has the id "both-gif". what am i doing wrong?

Comment: We cannot tell without your HTML and CSS. Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - but the first mistake is using jQuery on  DOM element

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("both-gif").addClass("animated bounce")
```

here `addClass` is a jQuery function. it won't work in JavaScript.

You can't chain jQuery function with `document.getElementById`
You need to change it to

```
document.getElementById("both-gif").classList.add("animated","bounce")
```

Also this line

```
document.getElementById("both-gif").removeClass("animated bounce")
```

to

```
document.getElementById("both-gif").classList.remove("animated","bounce")
```

Comment: mplungjan thanks for pointing. nope my mistake. it expects a comma seperated list

Comment: Only newer browsers and [not IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Browser_compatibility) support more than one argument on the add. and they need to be comma separated - I see your update.